Can be installed an instance of Adobe AEM 6.5 locally by means Ubuntu 22.4 guest virtual machine?
I have been trying to do that, yet I could and I guess it won't work. Once I checked which version of java this Ubuntu VM had by using java -version it displayed a message that there is not such programm installed. Then I seek for how install such programm but I found that there is not way to install that version of java on Ubuntu. So, there is an efficient way to installed AEM 6.5 by using Linux or Ubuntu?
Thanks in advance for your help!
